# In Zend Framework 2, how do override the layout based upon the route?

Tags: layout, zend-framework2, routes

Currently i have this to override the layout based upon the module;

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
        $controller      = $e->getTarget();
        $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
        $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));
        if ('Myrobot' === $moduleNamespace ) {
            $controller->layout('layout/myrobot');
        }
    }, 200);
}
```

I would like to change this so that the layout is base upon the route name not the module name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu can also search for a module which does set the layout based on the route name, such as [ZfcAdmin](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcAdmin/blob/master/Module.php#L112-L133). In the Module.php it grabs the currently matched route. If the route name starts with `admin`, then the layout it set.

Mind you have to check if the last returned view model is set to terminate. That means the controller doesn't want to render the layout, so you don't need to set the layout. Keep that in mind for your own piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need to gain access to the `Router` within your code snipped and get the currently matched route name. Then you simply check within your config if for that route-name a template entry exists and if it does, you overwrite it. With this information you should be able to keep on digging because just copy pasting `EdpModuleLayouts` doesn't count as "valid attempt to solve problem on your own" ;)

Comment: You can get access to the route match via the event, no need for the `Router` ;)

Comment: How do I access the route match from within the event?

Comment: True, MvcEvent has that, my bad :)